# c# - Binary Search Algorithm for Custom Class String List

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, binary-search

Basically I need help adapting my Binary Search Algorithm to work with my string list as seen below. **Note**, I have to use a written Binary Search algorithm, no use of built-in c# functions like .BinarySearch .

I will now show you how the list is formatted and the list itself:

```
// This class formats the list, might be useful to know

public class Demo
{
    public string Col;
    public string S1;
    public string S2;
    public string S3;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Col: {0}, S1: {1}, S2: {2}, S3: {3}", Col, S1, S2, S3);
    }
}

// The list itself

var list = new List<Demo>
        {   
            new Demo {Col = "Blue", S1 ="88", S2 ="Yes"},
            new Demo {Col = "Green", S1 ="43", S2 ="Yes"},
            new Demo {Col = "Red", S1 ="216", S2 ="No"},
            new Demo {Col = "Yellow", S1 ="100", S2 ="No"}
        };
```

The list is already sorted into alphabetical order of the 'Col' string values, hence why Blue is first and Yellow is last. The 'Col' is the part of the list that needs to be searched. Below I have inserted my current Binary Search that can search int arrays.

```
public static int BinarySearch_R(int key, int[] array, int low, int high)
    {
        if (low > high) return -1;
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (key == array[mid])
        {

            return mid;
        }
        if (key < array[mid]) {
            return BinarySearch_R(key, array, low, mid - 1);
        } else {
            return BinarySearch_R(key, array, mid + 1, high);
        }
    }
```

I need help adapting my BinarySearch Algorith to work for the list above. If you guys have any questions, or need to see more of my code, just ask.

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36663070/c-sharp-binary-search-string-list#comment60918731_36663070

Comment: And again : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36663070/c-sharp-binary-search-string-list

Comment: @jdweng I've asked a slightly different question. No trying to argue just say :)

Comment: @Fabien I've asked a slightly different question. No trying to argue just say :)

Comment: What you have is not a string list, but custom class (`Demo`) list. You'd better update the post title (for instance something like "*Binary Search Algorithm by a property of a List element") because it's misleading.

Comment: @IvanStoev Okay, thanks for letting me know. As you can tell I'm not great at programming. Do you have any idea how to find a solution for my  issue? Maybe you know someone?

Comment: AS I said in previous posting make class 'ICompariable' and create a method CompareTo()

Answer (score 1):

**Concrete answer:** Adapting your method for the specific case is quite easy.

Let first update your existing method to use a more general method ([`IComparable<T>.CompareTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43hc6wht(v=vs.110).aspx) for comparing rather than the `int` operators:

```
public static int BinarySearch_R(int key, int[] array, int low, int high)
{
    if (low > high) return -1;
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    int compare = key.CompareTo(array[mid]);
    if (compare == 0)
    {
        return mid;
    }
    if (compare < 0)
    {
        return BinarySearch_R(key, array, low, mid - 1);
    }
    else {
        return BinarySearch_R(key, array, mid + 1, high);
    }
}
```

Then all you need is to copy/paste the above method, replace `int key` with `string key`, `int[] array` with `List<Demo> array` and `array[mid]` with `array[mid].Col`:

```
public static int BinarySearch_R(string key, List<Demo> array, int low, int high)
{
    if (low > high) return -1;
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    int compare = key.CompareTo(array[mid].Col);
    if (compare == 0)
    {
        return mid;
    }
    if (compare < 0)
    {
        return BinarySearch_R(key, array, low, mid - 1);
    }
    else {
        return BinarySearch_R(key, array, mid + 1, high);
    }
}
```

**Extended answer:** While you can do the above, it will require you to do the same for any other property/class you need such capability.

A much better approach would be to generalize the code. For instance, `int[]` and `List<Demo>` can be generalized as `IReadOnlyList<T>`, `int/string key` as `TKey key`, `Demo.Col` as `Func<T, TKey>`, `CompareTo` as `IComparer<TKey>.Compare`, so the final generic method could be like this:

```
public static class MyAlgorithms
{
    public static int BinarySearch<T, TKey>(this IReadOnlyList<T> source, Func<T, TKey> keySelector, TKey key, IComparer<TKey> keyComparer = null)
    {
        return source.BinarySearch(0, source.Count, keySelector, key, keyComparer);
    }

    public static int BinarySearch<T, TKey>(this IReadOnlyList<T> source, int start, int count, Func<T, TKey> keySelector, TKey key, IComparer<TKey> keyComparer = null)
    {
        // Argument validations skipped
        if (keyComparer == null) keyComparer = Comparer<TKey>.Default;
        int lo = start, hi = start + count - 1;
        while (lo <= hi)
        {
            int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
            int compare = keyComparer.Compare(key, keySelector(source[mid]));
            if (compare < 0)
                hi = mid - 1;
            else if (compare > 0)
                lo = mid + 1;
            else
                return mid;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Now you can use that single method for any data structure. For instance, searching your `List<Demo>` by `Col` would be like this:

```
int index = list.BinarySearch(e => e.Col, "Red");
```

Comment: Very useful! Has helped me fix my issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ive only done the most basic things in C# so this might just be completely useless. I had an assignment for CS 2 class where at least it sounds somewhat similar to what you want but we use java. So im going to assume you want your list of items sorted by some keyword ("Blue","Green" etc...). I used a LinkedList but it doesnt matter.

```
    class Node {
    String keyword;
    LinkedList<String> records = new LinkedList<>();
    Node left;
    Node right;


    public Node(String keyword, LinkedList<String> records) {
        this.keyword = keyword;
        this.records = records;
    }
}
```

Now, the only real difference at least i can tell between having a BST sorted by a string and one sorted by numbers is that you need some type of comparison method to see whether one word is > or < in alphabet. So here's how i did the insert function:

```
   /**
 * insert node
 * @param keyword compare it to other strings
 */
public void insert(String keyword, LinkedList<String> records) {
    //create a new Node
    Node n = new Node(keyword, records);
    int result;
    Node current = root;
    Node parent = null;


    //cont. until NULL
    while (current != null) {
        result = current.keyword.compareTo(n.keyword);
        if (result == 0) return;
        else if (result > 0) {
            parent = current;
            current = current.left;
        }
        else if (result < 0) {
            parent = current;
            current = current.right;
        }
    }

    if (parent == null) root = n;
    else {
        result = parent.keyword.compareTo(n.keyword);
        if (result > 0) parent.left = n;

        else if (result < 0) parent.right = n;

    }
}
```

So the method "compareTo(...)" returns 1 if string is higher in alphabet 0 if same and -1 if lower. So i would, if im at all close to getting what youre asking, get the C# version of this method and implement BST as you normally would.

Answer (score 0):

Just create make class IComparable and create a custom CompareTo() method. The standard methods like sort will automatically work once the class inherits IComparable.

```
   public class Demo : IComparable 
    {
        public string Color;
        public int value;
        public Boolean truth;


        public int CompareTo(Demo other)
        {
            int results = 0;
            if (this.Color == other.Color)
            {
                if (this.value == other.value)
                {
                    results = this.truth.CompareTo(other.truth);
                }
                else
                {
                    results = this.value.CompareTo(other.value);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                results = this.Color.CompareTo(other.Color);
            }

            return results;
        }
```